# Transact SQL - Rollback, Variable Scope, Exiting

Tags: sql, transactions, scope

The somewhat minimal minimal version of what I'm trying to do boils down to this:

```
declare @VERSION_TO NVARCHAR(255); 
declare @VERSION_CURRENT NVARCHAR(255); 
set @VERSION_TO = '3.0.4401';

select @VERSION_CURRENT = VERSION from T_SYSTEM_INFO;

print 'target version:      ' + @VERSION_TO
print 'current version:    ' + @VERSION_CURRENT
if not @VERSION_CURRENT IN ('3.0.4300')
begin
     raiserror( 'Patch not possible - unknown predecessor "%s"', 17, 10, @VERSION_CURRENT)
     return
end

alter table T_JOB add CREATED [datetime];
update T_JOB set CREATED = (select top 1 STEP_START from T_JOB_STEP where T_JOB_STEP.JOB = T_JOB.ID and T_JOB_STEP.ID not in (select STEP from T_JOB_STEP_DEPENDENCY));
update T_JOB set CREATED = '01-01-2000' where T_JOB.CREATED is null;
alter table T_JOB alter column CREATED [datetime] not null;
update T_SYSTEM_INFO set VERSION = @VERSION_TO; 

go
```

but it fails on the update after the first ALTER TABLE:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>     Invalid column name 'CREATED'.

if I put a 'go' after the ALTER TABLE, it works, but fails on the last UPDATE:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
>     Must declare the scalar variable "@VERSION_TO".

I understand the scope of variables is limited by the go statements. I only want to have one at the end, anyways, so changes are rolled back if anything goes wrong. And if none of this is possible, how can I exit the whole script if there is an error, not just the transaction?

could anybody google the answer for me, please? :)

thanks

Comment: No offense, but couldnt you google the answer?

Comment: I was being sarcastic, because I was so frustrated I didn't find the answer myself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just redefine @VERSION_TO and set it after your alter table DDL? 
NOTE: transactions and DDL don't mix, i.e. you can't rollback an `alter table`.

Have you looked at sqsh? it is a SQL "shell" to replace isql that could help a lot here.

Comment: Well, I could, but the script is a lot bigger and there are lot more variables. Is there no way to expand the variable scope?